# Comparar que una fechas en formato timestamptz, PostgreSQL, Sequelize

Tags: nodejs, postgresql, sequelize.js

Estoy teniendo problemas al comparar dos fechas en timestamptz, tengo una tabla con un campo fecha de expiración y necesesito comparar, que una fecha no sea mayor a la de expiración que esta en la tabla, estoy usando Sequelize

```
let ahora = new Date();
function verificar (id, ahora) {
 return modelo.findOne({
  where: {
    id,
    fecha_exp: {
    [Op.gte]: ahora
   }
  }      
 });
}
```

Les agradeceria su colaboración